# Xamarin Bluetooth Scan

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth

today i started developing with C# and i tried to scan for a beacon.
This is how far i came..

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);            
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        BluetoothAdapter oBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
        BluetoothLeScanner oScanner = oBluetoothAdapter.BluetoothLeScanner;

        ScanCallback oCallback;



        if(!oBluetoothAdapter.IsEnabled)
        {
            StartActivity(new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ActionRequestEnable));
        } 
        else
        {
            oScanner.StartScan(oCallback);
        }
    }
```

The Problem is that i dont know how to use the Callback Parameter of the **StartScan** function. Can sombody please tell me how to use the callback right ?

Comment: Have you tried extending `ScanCallback` by your base class?

Comment: I think you mean to add a delegate to oCallback.OnScanResult ?

Comment: I'm an android guy so i'm used to Java, sorry :) In any case, yes, delegating `oCallback.OnScanResult` or extending the `ScanCallback` and implementing `OnScanResult` method is the same thing. If the method is firing (which you'll find out with logs) then everything's good.

Answer (score 5):

On android the implementation would be something like this:

```
_Manager = (BluetoothManager)appContext.GetSystemService("bluetooth");
_Adapter = _Manager.Adapter;
_LeScanner = _Adapter.BluetoothLeScanner;
 _BluetoothScanCallback = new BluetoothScanCallback();
```

Then when you start your scan it would be something like this:

```
_LeScanner.StartScan(_BluetoothScanCallback);
```

where `BluetoothScanCallback` would be implemented using something like:

```
public class BluetoothScanCallback : ScanCallback
{
    public override void OnScanResult([GeneratedEnum] ScanCallbackType callbackType, ScanResult result)
    {
        base.OnScanResult(callbackType, result);
    }
}
```